# For some reason when I use Spring Boot with LocalDateTime variable, my database won't be created

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is what spring does when I start it. It won't even show an error, but it won't create my database.
When I removed LocalDateTime variables, it worked fine and the database is created. Can someone give me some help

2020-08-19 02:08:14.204  INFO 10972 --- [  restartedMain] workshop.WRealestateApplication          : Starting WRealestateApplication on DESKTOP-TUAMB9Q with PID 10972 (D:\Java WEB Basic\Workshop realestate\target\classes started by Borislav in D:\Java WEB Basic\Workshop realestate)
2020-08-19 02:08:14.207  INFO 10972 --- [  restartedMain] workshop.WRealestateApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-08-19 02:08:16.012  WARN 10972 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-08-19 02:08:16.194  INFO 10972 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-08-19 02:08:16.249  WARN 10972 --- [  restartedMain] ion$DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
2020-08-19 02:08:16.322  INFO 10972 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-08-19 02:08:16.415  INFO 10972 --- [  restartedMain] workshop.WRealestateApplication          : Started WRealestateApplication in 2.677 seconds (JVM running for 3.58)

Comment: @Column(name = "local_date_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime localDateTime;  //Above is an example of a column declaration in a JPA Entity class using LocalDateTime. Hope this may help.

Comment: That actually worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Great news Lallushe! And good luck